# Reading csv in colab errors

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm trying to import a file to c-lab. I've tried various versions https://buomsoo-kim.github.io/colab/2018/04/15/Colab-Importing-CSV-and-JSON-files-in-Google-Colab.md/

```
#import packages
import pandas as pd
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import io
print("Setup Complete")

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

# Read the file into a variable power_data
#power_data = pd.read("DE_power prices historical.csv")
data = pd.read_csv('DE_power prices historical.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Keep getting error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R01pW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method it works a bit easier:

1. Upload .csv files to your Google Drive
2. Run the following code in your Colab cell:

   ```
   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/drive')
   ```
3. Follow the link the output cell gives you and verify your Gmail account
4. Import using Pandas like:

   ```
   power_data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/*filename.csv*')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Mount google drive in google-colab

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

[image]

copy file path add into URL variable

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'add copy path your csv file'
df=pd.read_csv(url)
df.head()
```